# CFG Grammar for $L=\left\{ a^ib^jc^k\mid i+k=3j \right\}$

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

> Write a CFG Grammar for $L=\left\{ a^ib^jc^k\mid i+k=3j \right\}$

I'm having trouble because the j is in the middle so I keep getting c's before b's. I feel I'm missing something simple.

Comment: What makes you think $L$ is context-free?

Comment: @quasi: do you think it isn't?

Comment: @jason: hard to say what you are doing wrong without seeing it.

Comment: @quasi It's a question from a test I've seen. I think I found a solution. I will update in a little while with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it:

$S \rightarrow \varepsilon |aAbBcc|aaAbBc|aaaAbbBccc$

$A\rightarrow aaaAb|\varepsilon $

$B \rightarrow bBccc | \varepsilon $

The trick for me was having the first rule determine the differenace between $i$ and $k$ and then the other rules just preserve that.

Comment: Nice! (+1)${}{}{}{}$